# How do I validate a property from a different class with DataAnnotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a competition class and a competitionEntry class. A competition can have 5 questions (just string values) and the competitionEntry can have 5 answers (also only string values).

How would I validate that if a question is present that the answer should be present as well?

I think I need a custom validation attribute but how would I get the competition class properties to check if the answer is filled in and so the questions must also be?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with an attribute. It makes more sense to have the Competition class validate entries.

```
public class Competition
{
    public bool AnswersAreCorrectFor(CompetitionEntry entry)
    {
        // check answers
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I would like to do it via DataAnnotations as the next step would be the client side validation.

Comment: Sorry I misread the question. I'm not sure that there is a conditionally required validation attribute. You'd need a client side library that knows about one if you don't want to write the JS yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this but AFAIK, you can definitely do it with DataAnnotations.

You can implement a subclass of ValidationAttribute.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348218/xval-dataannotations-on-the-entire-class) to get the idea.